# Запись данных в таблицу SQLite

Tags: android, sqlite

Пишу Android приложение, есть список контактов, который я получаю с сервера и записываю в БД.А когда вывожу данные на экран, они выводятся не в том порядке, в котором их получил (всегда в разном), и не все данные.

Метод для записи в БД

```
public void addRec(final String firstName, final String lastName, final String image) {
    new Thread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            ContentValues cv = new ContentValues();
            cv.put(COLUMN_FNAME, firstName);
            cv.put(COLUMN_LNAME, lastName);
            cv.put(COLUMN_URL, image);
            sql.insertOrThrow(TABLE_FRIENDS, null, cv);
        }
    }).start();

}
```

вызывается в цикле

```
public static void updateBase (final Context context){
                    Contract contract=new Contract(context);
                    contract.openDB();
                    contract.delete();
                    for(int i=0;i<friends.size();i++) {
                        contract.addRec(friends.get(i).first_name,
                                        friends.get(i).last_name,
                                        friends.get(i).photo);
                    }
               }
```

Почему нарушается порядок данных? Как исправить?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

В реляционной модели данных порядок строк значения не имеет. SQLite в свою очередь, будучи реляционной БД, не гарантирует сохранение порядка добавления строк. Порядок строк вы определяете явно выражением `ORDER BY` в запросе. Если вам нужно сохранить порядк добавления - добавьте колонку с индексом `id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT`, а в запросе укажите `ORDER BY id ASC`.

Подробности здесь: http://sqlite.org/autoinc.html
и здесь: https://www.sqlite.org/lang_select.html#orderby

Comment: Дело в том, что строки добавляются не правильно, и не все. Т.е. из 84 контактов в таблицу записываются всего 70, или еще меньше. И когда просматриваю таблицу после добавления, они в произвольном порядке.

Comment: Только сейчас заметил. У вас на добавление каждой записи запускается новый тред. Вам это зачем? И вы уверены, что insertOrThrow() действительно thread safe?

Comment: Убрал запуск нового треда, порядок сохраняется, но некоторые записи пропущены. Видимо с потоками намудрил что то. Если усыпляю поток в цикле на 10мс, то все записывает.